# How to remove Bad magic number error in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyc

I have a python project which contains `app.py` and `source.py` files. Project also has other files for configs and logs. I have converted `app.py` to `app.exe` using `pyinstaller`

```
pyinstaller app.py
```

This has created a `dist` directory. I have copy pasted `source.py`, configs and the log files in the `dist` directory.

I also want to create a setup for this which will be installed on another machine. I cannot share the `source.py` file as it is thus instead of `.py` I have used `source.pyc`. I have now used inno compiler and have created a setup file.

As per my understanding, pyinstaller automatically binds the python interpreter so we do not need to install python on any other machine. I simply installed the exe and it started working fine.

In my project, I have a functionality which calls the `source.pyc` file like below:

```
exec(os.system("source.pyc install"))
```

This was working fine on my development machine but in other machine, it is giving me `bad magic error`.

As per online forums, this normally happens when we try to run the `pyc` file with different python version interpreter but in my case I am using the same pyinstaller interpreter. Then how come this error is coming.

Is there any other of compiling the additional files apart from app.py using pyinstaller. How can I remove this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller does not bundle or bind a Python interpreter with the EXE file. The EXE file is a *compiled* binary file which, as it is compiled, does not need an interpreter. A PYC file still requires an interpreter.

You can compile the other files (i.e. `source.py`) using PyInstaller as well, and then move the compiled EXE file to the same directory as `app.exe`. In that case you would be able to run your command of `import os; os.system("source.exe")` from the main program. If your other compiled scripts require modules/libraries not used/included in the `app.exe` compilation, then when moving the compiled `source.exe`, you will need to move the bundled libraries to the `app.exe` directory as well.